# SPARQL OPTIONAL with BIND not working in RDFlib

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdflib

I tried the following query and found that it works in rdf4j and not in rdflib. After doing some brute force, I found out that the query does not behave as expected only when there is a BIND within the OPTIONAL block. Is there any workaround for this?

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ex:<http://example.org#>


CONSTRUCT {
          
    ex:node1 rdfs:value ?testNode .

}
WHERE{
    ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .
    
    OPTIONAL { 
    ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .
    FILTER(?value = ex:test1) .
   
    BIND(BNODE() as ?testNode) .

    }
    OPTIONAL {
    ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .
    FILTER(?value != ex:test1) .
    BIND(rdfs:nil as ?testNode) .        
    }
}
```

So, technically, this query should yield a value with either `?testNode` to be `rdfs:nil` or a blank node.
e.g.

```
http://example.org#node1  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#value http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil
```

In rdf4j, it behaves as expected (yielding `rdfs:nil` or a blank node depending on the value of `ex:test1`). But, in rdflib the OPTIONAL part gets skipped, so I don't get any result.

Comment: is `ex1:test1` a typo? I mean there is no `ex1` prefix

Comment: Not that I understand the purpose of your query, and unfortunately you missed to provide sample data. But, you can maybe use `WHERE {
    ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .
    BIND(IF(?value = ex:test1, BNODE(), rdfs:nil ) AS ?testNode)
}`

Comment: @UninformedUser Yes, the `ex1:test1` is a typo. I was using some other namespace and I manually edited it while posting this question. So, I kinda made an error there. Now, I have made some changes, hope it is better understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why this behaves inconsistently as I cannot speak for the implementations, but I am also not surprised. The query is a bit overcomplicated; you don't need the individual `OPTIONAL` patterns when `?testNode` is left bound in both cases and you are not doing anything else (and the `ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .` there is redundant too):

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ex:<http://example.org#>

CONSTRUCT {
    ex:node1 rdfs:value ?testNode .
}
WHERE{
    ex:current_value rdfs:value ?value .
    BIND((IF(?value = ex:test1), BNODE(), rdfs:nil) as ?testNode) .
}
```